# 3 way right joins in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I don't quite understand my why code works but how does SQL do the joining process with 3 tables?
Heres the code with the table diagram below:

```
select category.category_id, name, count(film_id)
from films
right join film_category using (film_id)
right join category using (category_id)
group by category.category_id, name 
order by count desc, name
```

[image]

I selected films in the 2nd line and right joined it to film_category, can someone confirm that keeps the 'film_category' information if 'films' doesn't contain the same id? Does SQL just magically know it should join 'film_category' with 'category'? Does that mean I can shuffle the order of joins around then?
Thanks

Comment: A better query would be: `select c.category_id, c.name, count(fc.film_id) as cnt
from category c
inner join film_category fc on using fc.film_id = c.film_id
group by c.category_id, c.name
order by cnt desc, c.name`

Answer (score 0):

Most people don't recommend using `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`, for they are usually less readable than `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, as you must read the `FROM` clause backwards. I, too, advise not to use them.

You select from `category`, outer join `film_category` and then outer join `films`. Thus you select all categories with their films keeping categories in the result that have no associated film.

The query is wrong in only two regards:

- Semantical: With  `USING(film_id)` the `film_id` is never null, so `COUNT(film_id)` will not count zero when there is no film, but one.
- Syntactical: The `COUNT` in `ORDER BY` lacks its parameter.

The query would be more readable with left outer joins as mentioned. With `ON` instead of `USING` and all columns qualified with their table names and with alias names for readability:

```
select c.category_id, c.name, count(f.film_id)
from category c
left join film_category fc on fc.category_id = c.category_id
left join films f on f.film_id = fc.film_id
group by c.category_id, c.name 
order by count(f.film_id) desc, c.name;
```